# Class of the entities retrieved from a hierarchy

Tags: jpa

In my project, I have a JPA hierarchy `Location -> Site`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOCATION")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="LOC_TYPE",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Location {
  ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SI")
public class Site extends Location {
  ...
}
```

Now, every `Employee` has a list of `Location` assigned (even if, as far as I can tell, all such locations are actually `Site`). In some part, I need the list of `Site`s an `Employee` has assigned to (note, the relationship I have defined was to `Location`s).

With Hibernate 3.2, I can just write the query for `Location` and filter by the discriminant; the classes returned are instances of the more specific subclass, v.g.:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT loc FROM Location loc WHERE loc.type=\"SI\"");
List<Location> locations = (List<Location>) query.getResultList();
for (Location location : locations) {
  Site mySite = (Site) location;
  ...
}
```

However, I fail to find any documentation that tells if this behaviour is guaranteed by the JPA specification or is just an implementation decision from Hibernate. In the last case, I should not use that approach since it may change if I switch providers).

Can you tell me if my approach is supported by the standard?

BTW, I am using JPA 1 on Hibernate 3.2

UPDATE:

In orden to clarify what I want, this is the "safety alarm" that I have implemented. Keep in mind that the `disc` property is the discriminator column, so I am sure that the objects returned where persisted as `Site` instances.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT lo FROM Employee em JOIN em.location lo WHERE lo.disc = 'SI'");
List<Location> locations = (List<Location>) query.getResultList();
List<Site> site = new ArrayList<Site>();
for (Location location : locations) {
  if (location instanceof Site) {
    sites.add((Site) location);
  } else {
    log.warn("Found a Location that is not instance of Site");
  }
}
```

Does the JPA specification specify that my `log.warn` statement will never be called? AFAIK, maybe an implementation can return a bunch of `Location` that are not instances of `Site`. Of course, in that case only the `Location` properties would be available; the behavior being somewhat like slicing in C++.

Comment: I think you still did not explain your problem. Do you have a Java field `disc`, that is mapped to the `LOC_TYPE` DB column? If not, than you could simply try that. Additionally in your example: why not simply looking directly for the Site entities: `SELECT s FROM Site s WHERE...` ?

Comment: My JPQL was a little of a oversimplification, now it is more representative. I cannot just select `Site` entities because I get them through a navigation to the `Location` superclass. As a last solution I could have it solved with a subselect that returns the IDs from the `Location`s to a select of the `Site`s, but the issue has left me wondering about the question (also, I try to avoid `IN` subselects for performance issues).

Comment: 1. Subselect is worse than `IN`. 2. `IN` is never a problem, as long you do no have 1000 values. 3. You did not say anything about my first idea (maybe you use it already): simply add a JAVA field eType that maps to your `LOC_TYPE` DB discriminator column and use it in your queries.

Comment: If you are asking just for the record that are type of Site using discriminator column why you think you will obtain others than that. ?  this is the question if that event is possible?

Comment: @Koitoer The question is: the instance returned will be of type `Site`? My JPQL demands `Location`, so it could act like C++ slicing of objects and return `Location` instances with the contents of the row. Obviously, properties defined in `Site` would not be available (as happens with slicing), but I would still get what the JPQL query demanded. My question could be reworded as: Can I be sure that I will get an instance of the same class (or a proxy of that) used originally to store the entity? Twisted, I know, but found no specs that prevent it.

Answer (score 5):

In JPA beginning with version 2.0 you have the `TYPE(e)` function. Example from the spec:

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE TYPE(e) IN (Exempt, Contractor)
```

Excerpt from the JPA 2.0 spec (**4.6.17.4 Entity Type Expressions**):

> An entity type expression can be used to restrict query polymorphism.
>   The TYPE operator returns the exact type of the argument.

---

**Note JPA.** On the other side, your example casts doubt on the basic JPA mechanisms and I want to underline that again: when you fetch an row (using JPA queries) from DB with its discriminator value specific to the `Site` entity, you can be sure that the Java object will be an instance of that class (i.e of the `Site` class). Now I believe that the specification does not force the providers that its class is `Site` (i.e `fetchedEntity.getClass()==Site.class`), but you can be 100% sure that `fetchedEntity instanceof Site` returns true.

---

**Note Hibernate.** From my experience with Hibernate I can only add that `fetchedEntity.getClass() == Site.class` returns true in Hibernate (of course beside the fact that `fetchedEntity instanceof Site`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it is good to know this option. Anyway, the `WHERE` section is already covered because I filter by the discriminator, what I would want is some assurance that the `e` retrieved has actually been created as an `Exempt` or `Contractor` instance (and not just a plain `Employee`)

Comment: What do you mean by "section is already covered"? As I understand, this is exactly what you need (if supported in JPA 1.0): those employees will be exactly of those Java Types: `Exempt` or `Contractor`, and not a plain `Employee`.

Comment: JPA 1 does not support `TYPE` (I have just checked it). I work around it by filtering by the discriminator (as in my `JPQL`). Anyway what I want is the part of the specification (or absence of it) that ensures your last affirmation; I might be a little too apprehensive but I have the feeling that, if not specified by the docs, some implementation might return a plain `Employee` entity and not the original subclass (since that is what the `JPQL` "requests")

Comment: Well, that example is from the SPEC (as I have written before). I have added the interesting part from the spec. More than that I can only recommend to open the spec alone :)

Comment: Added a clarification to the question.

Comment: +1 I think @AndreiI have the point of this as was the first to answer, JPA in the specs is clearly said that restrict the query polymorphic , also I think your log.warn will be never happens although you try to retrieve using Parent class. I don't really know slicing c++ , sorry about it. Also I strongly suggest to use TYPE instead of lo.disc = 'SI', as this does not said anything about restrict polymorphism

Comment: @SJuan76 As JPA 2.0 is backward compatible with JPA 1.0, you have now a pretty good reason to upgrade. I added some comments related to your doubt.